# show a txt file in website and refresh as it changes without page refresh

Tags: javascript, text, refresh

i have a txt file that contains the status of some devices it looks like this

```
data.txt: 
90 = heat_index_limit
33 = lights_limit
45 = humidity_limit
500 = chart_life_time
off : AIRC
off : lights
off : shutters
```

these values change overtime. when a device turns on for example the air condition the line changes to on : AIRC

i want the status of these devices to show as they change on a web site in real time without refreshing the page (using a javascript i guess)

i already have a javascript refresh function that does this for an image that also changes all the time but i have trouble doing this for a text file. can you please help? i am noob in web design

this is the code i have tried so far

on html body:

```
   body onload="refresh(); refresh2();"
```

then :

```
<div id="status"></div>
```

and the script

```
</script>
<script language="javascript" type = "text/javascript">

function refresh2() {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function () {
                file = fopen(getScriptPath("data.txt"), 0);
                file_length = flength(file);
                $(".content").load("file.html");
                document.getElementById("status").innerText = content;    
        }
}
window.onload=function(){

    setInterval(function(){refresh2()}, 1000 ); 
}
</script>
```

Comment: With real-time display like this, you have to do some researches about websocket, not only javascript (on client-side) but also socket-server

Comment: Please add some more details about "i have trouble doing this for a text file"... what have you tried? How did it fail to work?

Comment: i added the code i tried last..hope it helps